# Campaign Tracking not working via playstore since apk split

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-firebase

I am facing a different problem since I last updated my app on android playstore, moreover, on searching the web I couldn't find any close question. Recently our APK size increased all of sudden. Upon inspection, it turned out that the libs platform is now supporting a newer version of CPU architecture (over 40% increase in size). At this point, we decided to split the APK as per CPU (via gradle).

After publishing this, we started facing the problem in campaign tracking. Our campaign tracking numbers decreased dramatically. We thought something went wrong, so we revisited the analytics integration, upgraded the SDK and its corresponding configuration file with the latest library(play-services-9.0.0). Also performed the campaign monitoring test. However our campaign tracking is still not working as expected (over 80% less attribution).

Can anyone point what am I missing in this setup? Thanks in advance :)

For the reference, I am posting the build.gradle, AndroidManifest.xml and the campaign receiver files.

build.gradle (identifiable info removed)

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    mavenCentral()
    flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
    }
}


android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.3'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.app"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0.0"
        renderscriptTargetApi 19
        renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            output.outputFile = new File(
                    output.outputFile.parent,
                    output.outputFile.name.replace(".apk", "-${variant.versionCode}-${variant.versionName}.apk"))
        }
    }
    splits {
        abi {
            enable true
            reset()
            include 'arm64-v8a', 'x86', 'armeabi', 'armeabi-v7a', 'mips'/*, 'x86_64', 'mips64'*/
            universalApk true
        }
    }
    sourceSets { main { assets.srcDirs = ['src/main/assets', 'src/main/assets/fonts'] } }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:9.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:9.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:9.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:9.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.0.0'
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.5.5@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    compile('com.twitter.sdk.android:tweet-composer:0.8.0@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.app" >
<!--android:installLocation="auto" for adoptable storage-->
    <uses-permission .... />

    <application
        android:name="com.example.app.toolbelt.ComBank"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Light" >
        ...
        <receiver
            android:name="com.example.app.services.campaign.CampaignReceiver"
            android:enabled="true" android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.CampaignTrackingReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <service android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.CampaignTrackingService" />
        <!-- Optionally, register AnalyticsReceiver and AnalyticsService to support background
         dispatching on non-Google Play devices -->
        <receiver android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.AnalyticsReceiver"
            android:enabled="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.ANALYTICS_DISPATCH" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <service android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.AnalyticsService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="false"/>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

CampaignReceiver.java

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;

import com.example.app.toolbelt.ComBank;
import com.example.app.toolbelt.Tracking;
import com.google.android.gms.analytics.CampaignTrackingReceiver;

import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.URLDecoder;

/**
 * Created by rokha on 1/8/15.
 */
public class CampaignReceiver extends CampaignTrackingReceiver {
    static final String TAG = CampaignReceiver.class.getSimpleName();
    Tracking tracking;
    Context mContext;


    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        String rawReferrer = intent.getStringExtra("referrer");

        Log.d(TAG, "received broadcast");

        if (rawReferrer != null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "raw: " + rawReferrer);

            String referrer = "";

            try {
                referrer = URLDecoder.decode(rawReferrer, "UTF-8");
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace(); // This should not happen.
            }

            Log.d(TAG, "decoded: " + referrer);

            if (ComBank.sharedPref.getString(CampaignHelper.REFERRED, "").length() == 0) {
                ComBank.editor.putString(CampaignHelper.REFERRER, referrer).commit();
            }
        } else {
            Log.e(TAG, "referrer is null");
        }
        super.onReceive(context, intent);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try changes in manifest like this, it will work**

```
<receiver
        android:name="*.InstallSourceReceiver"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter android:priority="10">
            <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER"/>
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data
            android:name="forward.GoogleAnalytic"
            android:value="com.google.analytics.tracking.android.CampaignTrackingReceiver" />
    </receiver>
```

Set priority if you are using multiple receiver for tracking.

To create the multiple apk for different CPU architecture you should use product flavours like this

```
productFlavors {
    x86 {
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard.cfg'
        versionCode 4 + defaultConfig.versionCode
        ndk {
            abiFilter "x86"
        }
    }
    mips {
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard.cfg'
        versionCode 3 + defaultConfig.versionCode
        ndk {
            abiFilter "mips"
        }
    }
    armv7 {
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard.cfg'
        versionCode 2 + defaultConfig.versionCode
        ndk {
            abiFilter "armeabi-v7a"
        }
    }
    arm {
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard.cfg'
        versionCode 1 + defaultConfig.versionCode
        ndk {
            abiFilter "armeabi"
        }
    }
}
```

Please also share your campaign tracking URL.

Comment: [Link1](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.example.app&referrer=utm_source%3Doffline%26utm_medium%3Dbanner%26utm_campaign%3DKT)

[Link2](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.example.app&referrer=utm_source%3DKA%26utm_medium%3Dbanner%26utm_campaign%3Dslogan)

Comment: زاهد نقفي I am sure all apks having diff version codes so it will take only the highest one so you need to take different GA keys and sent according to apk via gradle.

Have you made 5 apk of an application or something flavors ?

Comment: @zahid: Yes, I made 5 apk's (by running gradle 5 times earlier... have now deployed the above method as well because it is much better automation)

I think the android priority is the trick I was looking for. I still have to run a counter test as I deployed multiple solutions on my APK. Would post my results here once I have a better understanding.